# How to export 20 000 contacts from MySQL database via PHP for import into an desktop address book?

Tags: php, mysql, file, ms-office, export

I need to write a script to **export contact data** for **printing on stickers** for mailing. There could be up to **20 000** records in the database table.

The main problem is that the number of records could be so high and the site is hosted on a shared server and exporting the whole 20k records would, presumably, kill the script or stall.
I the numbers were not so high i would simply export all data into a hCard file.

The solution needs to be in PHP, and the resulting file must be usable by MS Office for use to print out address stickers.

**All ideas are welcome**!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm presuming that you DO have access to MySQL server. Why not connect to MySQL directly it should save you a LOT of time. If the operation takes to long or you expect performance issues then plan it at midnight.

You can export directly to csv like this,

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'result.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM my_table;
```

Load it in Word through mailmerge and of you go!

Answer (score 2):

20k records should be very fast to export to a CSV file. if your shared hosting is so resource-starved that it can't process 20k records in under a couple of seconds, then you've got bigger problems.

Answer (score 1):

Work in batches...

1. Load 50 Addresses into $i.csv.
2. reload your site (tip: header()), repeat for around 400 times.
3. copy the 400 cvs files into one big one (even by using notepad).
4. Open e.g. with Excel.

Comment: Why make a bunch of .csv files? You could use  a+ with file open to append to it. $handle = fopen("c:\\data\\file.csv", "a+");

Comment: It was my understanding that the script runs on a server and the user wants the csv locally. Agreed, you could append the file remotely and then just download it...

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the host, but you can generally allow for longer script execution times by using   [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php).  This coupled with dumping the data into a csv file is one way.  As longneck has stated, 20k records should be faster than the 30 seconds usually allotted for scripts to run.

Answer (score 0):

Code example: (I already had to do this)

```
$static_amount = 100; // 100 Entries to the same time
for($i = 0; $i < $mysql->count(); $i+$static_amount)
{
$toFile[$i] = $mysql->query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id < $i AND id > $static_amount');
sleep(10); // very important!!!
}
```

OR

```
if($_COOKIE['amount'])
{
$_COOKIE['amount'] = 100;
}

$toFile = $mysql->query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > $_COOKIE['alreadyPerformed'] LIMIT $_COOKIE['amount']';
setCookie('amount') = 100;
setCookie('alreadyPerformed') = $_COOKIE['alreadyPerformed'] + 100;
```